# DRY self-replicating type

Tags: f#, clone

Is there a succint way to express self-replicating types in F#? — That is, without repeating oneself.

```
// Manual self-replication

type Foo (par1 : Type1, par2 : Type2, par3 : Type3, par4 : Type4) =

    let unique = new UniqueState() // unique for every instance of Foo

    member this.SelfReplicate =
        new Foo(par1, par2, par3, par4) // repeating myself

let a = new Foo(x, y, z, w)
let b = a.SelfReplicate
```

Attempt with manually injected self-replicator:

```
// Semi-automagic self-replication

type Foo' (par1 : Type1, par2 : Type2, par3 : Type3, par4 : Type4, replicate : unit -> Foo') =

    let unique = new UniqueState() // unique for every instance of Foo'

    member this.SelfReplicate = replicate() // not repeating myself

let rec foo' () = new Foo'(x, y, z, w, foo')
let a = foo'()
let b = a.SelfReplicate
```

I'm not sure how this can be any more succint without compiler magic. It just seems like there should be a way to capture the current arguments and type without repeating them syntactically.

Comment: I see you create a record of types. Where is the definition of  UniqueState() - feels like a singleton pattern here.    Presumably you want a=b to be true.  Records are immutable so once created you can repeatedly use. What is your use case for this?  I can't see What the motivation to do this is.

Comment: UniqueState is left out on purpose. It is supposed to be the opposite of a singleton. Think of it as a globally unique integer for each instance of Foo or Foo', if you will.

Comment: Technically you can use Json serialization - deserialization, but it's slow and creating copy of object seems like bad pattern in F# with immutable types by default

Comment: It is not an exact copy - UniqueState is distinct. Otherwise the exercise would be pointless. This problem is not about mutability per se. I think you're right though that a serialization roundtrip is not the best mechanism to use for replication. :-)

Comment: Two ideas: 1) Use a record type instead of a class type. You can easily clone a record via `{ foo with unique = UniqueState() }`. 2) Use reflection to enumerate and copy a class type's fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a type `WithUnique<'T>` which is a wrapper over a value of type `'T` and adds a unique value to this. You may need to think about how you want the equality testing on those types to work - if you use record (as I do below), then two instances with different unique value will not be equal:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let uniqueState() = rnd.Next()

type WithUnique<'T> = 
  { Value : 'T; Unique : int }
  static member Create(v) : WithUnique<'T> = 
    { Value = v; Unique = uniqueState() }
  member x.Replicate() = 
    { Value = x.Value; Unique = uniqueState() }
```

The value of `'T` is just one type, but this can be a tuple (or a record) if you need to wrap multiple things:

```
let wu1 = WithUnique.Create( (10, "hi") )
let wu2 = wu1.Replicate()
```

Given the above, `wu1=wu2` will be `false`.

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution for record types. In my case equality testing is not of interest. I didn't mention that the types in play are not record types - but they aren't - as good as they are in many cases. Still, this is a perfectly valid answer to my question. :-)